# Codeigniter: view mysql data in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem.
I cannot echo my assoc table in view. print_r is showing that there is only one uname,
Controller:

```
    $this->db->select('uname, uid, content, date');
    $this->db->join('users','posts.p_uid = users.uid');
    $this->db->from('posts');
    $posts = $this->db->get();
    foreach($posts->result_array() as $row){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    print_r($data);
    $this->load->view('posts',$data);
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 border p-0 offset-md-4 ">
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 border">
<?php print_r($uname); ?>
</div> 
</div>
```

print_r result from controller:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [uname] => admin 
        [uid] => 6 
        [content] => test test test test test test test test 
        [date] => 2018-06-27 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [uname] => admin 
        [uid] => 6 
        [content] => test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 
        [date] => 2018-06-26 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [uname] => admin2 
        [uid] => 7 
        [content] => test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 
        [date] => 2018-06-17 
    ) 
)
```

print_r result from View: `admin2`

Comment: I want to have Array ([0] => 'admin' [1] =>'admin' [2] =>'admin2') in $uname in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not passing your `uname` parameter to your view:

Check below:

```
foreach($posts->result_array() as $row){
        $data['uname'][] = $row;      // Set the parameter to pass to your view will be array
    }
```

This will give the `array` of `uname, uid, content, date`.

If you want to pass your field value to your view then do like below may help.

I think your answer as below **(as per your comment).**

```
foreach($posts->result_array() as $row){
            $data['uname'][] = $row['uname'];      // Set the parameter to pass to your view will be your value
        }
```